# Is it time to invite nominations for our 150th day anniversary awards?

Tags: discussion

If I am right in thinking that IPS.SE was launched on June 27, then we have completed 150 days today. (Do the math: it's Nov.27 with five 30-day months, but July, August and October have 31, so 150 days were completed 3 days early: on 24 November 2017.) As always a **best answers contest** would be very encouraging and I shall contribute 300 points rep for the second best answer. Who wants to sign up for donating the first prize 500 rep and the third prize 200 rep? We might allow nominations to include answers written upto 30th of November, and I would appreciate a moderator creating an official contest post here on meta.

---

**Update**: @Catija in her very prompt answer feels it would be better to extend contests to quarterly basis and have the next contest in January 2018 for answers written between October 1 and December 31, starting a regular cycle of quarterly contest 4 times a year, which I think is **a very good suggestion**. My meta question here was not intended as a contest announcement and I just want to know how the community plans to schedule the next contest.

Comment: I'll just add that when I started the first awards, 50 days in, I just meant it to be a one-time thing, as a way to look back at some of the best content in the earliest days of the site/

Comment: It was certainly a good idea @HDE 226868 -- like many other SE sites, we can institutionalise the feature as the quarterly awards. In addition to highlighting the best content, such contests also remind us to share reputation points. What about a recurring special quarterly award for *best question?*

Answer (score 6):

Now that we've passed the first 100 days, I think we should switch to what some of the other sites do - quarterly awards. This is easier to track as it goes by month and isn't too frequent - four times per year. As such, I recommend we do our first quarterly awards for the fourth quarter of 2017 - posts written between October 1st 2017 and December 31st 2017. With the [100 day post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1883/36) running through October 10th, this will offer a small amount of overlap but not a lot. We can further exclude from nominations any post that won in the prior award.

I think that every 50 days is a bit too frequent.

Comment: I thought so as well.  That is why I invited discussion before posting any contest notice @Catija!

Comment: Something we've found helpful on Mi Yodeya is: we post the "call for nominations" post at the *beginning* of the quarter so that people can add nominations when they see good new posts (rather than having to remember later), *but* we tell people not to vote until we open voting at the end of the quarter.  Here's an [example](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4410/472) for the current quarter, and a [past one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4361/472) (edit history might be helpful).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Interesting. How do you keep people from voting during the quarter?

Comment: It's possible that *only votes cast after the official start-voting date* would be counted towards the contest score @Catija.

Comment: @ Catija I think the timeline would show daily vote summaries and we can discount the votes cast before the start date. So a few rebel votes won't affect it by much. It's too tempting for me to vote now. LOL. I won't vote. Don't worry. @MonicaCellio

Comment: @Catija we leave comments on each answer (with bold text) saying not to vote yet, and delete them when voting opens.  So far that's worked.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, funny thing about those comments, see my above comment.. As a rebel since birth, I had this strong urge to go ahead and vote there.. lol. (But I hold back) :)

Comment: @NVZ I'm glad you can restrain yourself.  It'd be a real pain to have to lock posts and then unlock them later. :-(

Comment: @MonicaCellio if there's an option to lock voting for a post, that'd be nice. But it still should be able to be edited to improve and new answers should be addable.

Comment: That's why locks are a pain; they lock votes *and* edits.  I didn't mean locking the question, though; that'd defeat the purpose.  Mods would have to lock every answer as it gets posted.  But only if the site has users who aren't willing to heed polite requests to follow the rules.  So with luck it's not an issue.