# Please nominate and vote on answers for the quarterly awards contest October-December 2017

Tags: discussion

***Update***: The contest notice has been posted at [Nominations for the best answer of the fourth quarter 2017](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/nominations-for-the-best-answer-of-the-fourth-quarter-2017) I am glad to note that @apaul has [put up](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/nominations-for-the-best-answer-of-the-fourth-quarter-2017#comment5695_2383) 500 points for the **first prize** and I shall post a 300 points bounty myself for the **second best voted answer.** @Snow has also kindly volunteered to [share points](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/are-we-ready-to-announce-the-quarterly-awards-contest-for-october-december-2017#comment5693_2373), presumably the bounty of 150 for the **third prize.**

**However, only one answer has been nominated in the first week -- I nominated it -- and the contest expires on Feb 1.** So please do nominate a few more deserving answers and vote on them!

---

Original question (archived here):

When I asked a [meta question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/is-it-time-to-invite-nominations-for-our-150th-day-anniversary-awards) about the 150th day [awards contest](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/100-days-has-gone-by-time-to-reward-your-hard-work) in November there was a general consensus that we were going towards the **quarterly award pattern** with the first contest to be announced in January for answers submitted in the period October 1 to December 31.

So December 31 is past as is January 15.

Are we ready to announce the quarterly awards contest for October-December 2017?

I suppose the awards pattern will be 500, 300 and 200 points bounty for the first, second and third voted answers.

**Members who wish to contribute award bounties can pledge their awards by writing short answers to this meta question.** Please specify which prize you want to support and what amount you shall donate.

If members are in agreement and once we get all those awards pledged,  I request a moderator to put up the formal contest notice.

Comment: A contest notice would need to be accompanied by pledges for the other 700 rep, so anybody willing to offer that could make the post -- doesn't need to be a mod.  (I don't remember who was offering these bounties before.)

Comment: Honestly it didn't seem like people were too excited by the last few contests...

Comment: The [second](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/100-days-has-gone-by-time-to-reward-your-hard-work) contest was much more popular than the [first](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/rewarding-the-best-answers-in-the-first-50-days-of-interpersonal-skills) @apaul. We do need these awards to run timely and on a regular basis to emphasise quality and promote the ethic of sharing reputation points.

Comment: If it gains traction, I'd be happy to throw some rep at it, just wasn't sure if people were really interested.

Comment: It will gain traction if we conduct regular quarterly contests, thanks @apaul. I think people just never had previous experience of such a  concept, because many members of IPS were not previously very experienced elsewhere on SE.

Comment: I am also happy to contribute some of my coinage.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Snow. You can sponsor the third prize (200 points bounty).

Comment: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/nominations-for-the-best-answer-of-the-fourth-quarter-2017

Comment: Thanks to @Catija for posting the contest notice.

Comment: Please stop reusing this post to ask new questions.

Comment: Is it better to create a new post @Catija?

Comment: Or comment on the actual post asking? But, I'm sorry, I'm really struggling to see any value to anyone else on the site of this contest. This is what happened to the last  one and I really don't see any change any time soon.

Comment: Well we have tried it out (as we needed to) and the 3 contests taken together certainly had a lukewarm response. I am more than willing to accept the community consensus on that matter @Catija. In other words, I shall not wonder if we should have a best answers quarterly awards January-March contest in April. But do we need to extend the voting period of this one?

Comment: I don't see what extending the window would do... if they haven't put them up at this point, I don't think that more time will change that. Why don't you just award the bounty to that answer yourself, since you're the one who nominated it. If you find answers you like in the future, you can always give them an award on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

I shall be glad to post 300 points rep bounty for the **second best voted** answer.