# Nominations for the best answer of the fourth quarter 2017

Tags: discussion

Because you asked so nicely...

### Introducing the first quarterly Best Answer Nominations Post (Belated)

In an effort to reward answers that deserve additional attention, we're offering bounties for the top three answers of the quarter.

The rules:

- Write an answer to this post with a link to the answer you're nominating and a short paragraph explaining why the answer is one of the best. Only nominate one answer in each meta answer.
- The answer *must* have been written after October 1st 2017 0:00 UTC but prior to January 1st 2018 0:00 UTC.
- No self-nominations allowed! Let's try to be generous to other people.
- The meta nomination answer with the most upvotes - not net score, but *upvotes* - wins. **The score of the actual answer does not matter;** remember, some of the best answers may have gone unnoticed.
- The #1 answer will get a bounty of +500, the #2 answer will get a bounty of +300, and the #3 answer will get a bounty of +150.
- Voting ends on February 1st, 2018 0:00 UTC.

May the best answer win!

Comment: "I got 5 on it..." 500 that is.

Comment: Really nice of you to sponsor the 500 point first prize @apaul. I am awarding the 300 point second prize and Snow has [volunteered](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/are-we-ready-to-announce-the-quarterly-awards-contest-for-october-december-2017#comment5693_2373) as well, presumably for the 150 point third prize.

Comment: I have indeed.  It's going to be difficult to choose good answers, since we're basically looking at the majority of the answers here.

Comment: One of the best functions of quarterly awards contest is to highlight excellent answers that did not get sufficient attention at the time for whatever reason, @Snow. So I would request users who vote for a nomination here to actually reward the original answer with an upvote!

Comment: Cool, I started contributing just in time to be eligible to win! =D Though, really, don't think any of my answers are _that_ special. But this will be great for showcasing many excellent answers, so awesome!

Comment: Is there any way to highlight/reward especially good *questions*? I'm thinking not so much of questions with interesting or compelling topics (those are partially up to chance) as questions that do a really good job of explaining relevant context and priorities. I thought the question about explaining that "I am not your IT guy" was a good example of this. OPs who do a good job responding to comments to edit an off-topic question to be on-topic could also be commended.

Comment: @1006a We could create a similar meta post for questions but there's no way to reward them. They do this on Movies & TV... they have two posts... one for [Q&A](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2017) and one for [A only](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-3rd-quarter-of-2017).

Comment: A challenge I'm facing with this (and did with the previous ones too) is *going back and finding them*.   If there were someplace to note outstanding answers when we see them, for consideration in the *next* challenge, that would help me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio you mentioned something about how you do it on Judaism, I think? Maybe we should try that for this first quarter awards?

Comment: @MonicaCellio : *If there were someplace to note outstanding answers when we see them* -> I use *favorite* to easily find them back. I mark them and keep them aside.

Comment: Am I right to suppose that the voting period has now ended @Catija?

Comment: @EnglishStudent nope. 12 minutes yet.

Comment: OMG I miscalculated @Catija. India is 5:30 hours *ahead* of (not behind) UTC. Ok fine!

Comment: Please note @Catija: an answer was newly nominated 3 hours back by Anne Daunted, maybe forgetting the voting deadline. We could possibly extend voting by a few days, and give all 3 nominations a chance, or else I request you to please announce the result.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Seeing the lack of activity on these bounty giveaways, I think it's time we retire this thing for now. Maybe the next giveaway should be a year later, not quarterly.

Comment: That's all right @NVZ. 3 contests offer sufficient evidence that it is not a very popular exercise.

Answer (score 3):

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/8141/381

This answer by user [Dzyann](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/8855/dzyann) is extremely thorough in walking the reader step by step through every aspect of the motivations of OP, which is myself here, and the answer also gives some very sensible suggestions. After reading it I got a really good idea of what I want to achieve and how to approach the problem from an interpersonal perspective. **I can also report some good results already, by proceeding on the basis of that advice.** So I think this is one of the best answers of October-December 2017 and I nominate it for these quarterly awards!

Answer (score 1):

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/7979/3619

This answer by PoloHoleSet is a creative take on what I feel is a fairly common issue with teens and young adults. No one wants to lose money, after all!

But I also like it because even discussing the idea can really draw attention to the fact that something in the dynamic needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/6851/2625

I nominate this answer by [anongoodnurse](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/2708/anongoodnurse), because it is thorough, but neither too long nor too short. It covers both cases the OP could run into and gives excellent advice, honoring the premise (the OP doesn't want to come across as rude or selfish). She offers suggestions on what to say. In addition, to links are included at the end for further reading.